# $routeParams.id is undefined

Tags: .net, angularjs

I am passing a ID through url but i am getting undefined here is my angular code

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/Movie/Index/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/Movie/Index'
    })

    app.controller('urlController', ['$scope', '$http', 'idService', '$sce', 'ngDialog', '$route', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, idService, $sce, ngDialog, $route ,$routeParams) {
        $scope.displayMovie = function () {
            $http.get("/Movie/getLinks/", { params: { movID: localStorage.getItem('movID') } }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.linkList = response.data;
            })
        }
        console.log("routeparams" + $routeParams.id);
```

Here is my Html Code

```
<a href="/Movie/Index/{{movie.ID}}" ng-click="getID(movie.ID)" ><img ng-src="{{movie.picLink}}" title="{{movie.movieName}}" style="width:230px; height:115px;" /></a>
```

I am getting this url in the address bar

```
http://localhost:46134/Movie/Index/2
```

But still i am getting $route.Params.id = undefined.

What i am missing??? Please help

Comment: Are you actually getting anything printed in the console? Just curious as you aren't specifying the controller in your route declaration.

Comment: yeah i am getting undefined. Actually i specified my controller in the body tag of that page

Comment: I think your problem is you do not declare controller `urlController` in your route?

Comment: Can you try specifying it in the route declaration? I would expect ng-controller to be fine, but perhaps there's something in the routing when it instantiates the $routeParams service.

Comment: i have already done that no luck :\

Comment: In the templateUrl, if you use a function, you can get the route params as the first parameter: templateUrl: function(rp) { console.log(rp.id; return '...' } - just to confirm it is being passed?

Comment: show your full code? Where you are try to get $routeParams.id?.

Comment: At console.log("routeparams" + $routeParams.id); its given in the code

Comment: @zaidkhan see my answer edited. I just added a snippet. This should work for you too. Check it out and tell me if it was useful to you.